# Can't get text from didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have added tableview on top of `UIViewController` and I have also implemented the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` methods

For some reason, I am not getting the value out of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath.` I get the expected value of `indexPath.row` but the `selectedCell.textLabel.text` returns `nil`.

I am not able to figure out what may be the problem. I am using the dynamic table.

```
//Array of multiple objects is filled through the delegated arrays and the arrays are properly filled.
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return _arrayForMultipleObjects.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    // Configure the cell...
   _singleSelectionLabel= (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:2];
   _singleSelectionLabel.text=[self.arrayForMultipleObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        return cell;
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *valu ;
    NSLog(@"%i count",indexPath.row);
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"%@",cellText);
//Here cellText is null
    if([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType==UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
    {   [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        valu = cellText;
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",valu);
}
```

Comment: Can you please show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method as well.

Comment: Thanks Abhinav. I jst edited the whole question to accommodate the tableview delegate and datasource methods I have.

Comment: Don't get the text from the cell. Get the text from the data source.

Comment: I think I guessed it rightly. You are dropping a label `singleSelectionLabel` from story board and accessing wrong textLabel via code. Please check my post.

Comment: Thanks ready and Abhinav. I was doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using storyboard then the default cell style of table cells is `Custom` which gives you a blank cell where you can add other types of controls to it.

If you dragged a label onto the cell and changed its text, then you are likely using a Custom style of `UITableViewCell`.

The property textLabel is only available on cells of types other than Custom, such as Basic, or Detailed.

Please double check if this is the case for you.

Edit: As ready suggested you can fetch the text like this:

```
self.arrayForMultipleObjects[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: Thanks Abhinav. I was doing the way you just explained. I just fixed it and it works great.

Comment: Glad it helped! Could you please accept the answer so others could also get benefitted. @Rosh

Comment: @Rosh Did you fix it by getting the text from the data source and not from the label?

Comment: Thanks rmaddy. It worked and the issue was as you guys (Abhinav and you) pointed out.